# Model Initialization from SQL Schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using Flask to create a web application. The database is served by sqlite3. Is there a way to generate models automatically using the schema similarly to Django's `inspectdb`?

Comment: Are you using an ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy has a wonderful tool authored by Alex Grönholm called [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlacodegen/1.1.0).

```
pip install sqlacodegen
sqlacodegen sqlite:///database.db
```

It'll spit out a SQLAlchemy model based on the supplied database.  It's a great time-saver.  You can also choose to directly use the [reflection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/reflection.html) features of SQLAlchemy to achieve the same, or similar results.